# Different standard errors under Mac and PC in "effects" R package

Tags: lme4-nlme, effects

I ran a model with lme4::lmer() on my Mac, then predicted values and standard errors of the interaction with effects::Effect(). Then I tested the same code under Windows. Everything was identical besides estimated standard results. How do I solve it? What's the matter?

Here is a reproducible example. Data is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/s0zu2hqmmvvqpvx/d.Rdata?dl=1

```
load("d.Rdata")
m <- lme4::lmer(dep.var ~  ind.var * group.var + (1 | group), data=d)

pred.eff <- effects::Effect(c("ind.var", "group.var"),
                            mod=m, 
                            xlevels=list(group.var=c(-1,0)),
                            se=list(type="Scheffe", level=0.95)
             )

head(pred.eff$se)
```

On Mac I get SEs:

```
[1] 0.2991568 0.2880312 0.2833644 0.2887387 0.3083727 0.1530373
```

If I run exactly the same code on PC I get much smaller SEs:

```
[1] 0.09910418 0.05888546 0.02938689 0.06196380 0.12333139 0.06006961
```

As you can see, the differences aren't small. I suppose something is wrong with my data, as I weren't able to reproduce these discrepancies with simulations.

Comment: Could you post a few statistical summaries and/or graphics of the two datasets, *as produced when you are running `lmer`*, to demonstrate that they really are the same?  It's possible that something as minor (and subtle) as different conventions for reading files could be causing the systems to be working with different data, and that your problem is really with the computers--not with `R`, the data, or statistics.  BTW, a reproducible example is nice--but a *minimal* reproducible example is far better.  Do you really need to share over 40,000 observations in order to demonstrate the problem?

Answer (score 5):

I don't have a definitive answer, but here are some observations based on trying out your data:

- I can replicate your MacOS/larger-SE results on Linux (development version of R, lme4 devel/1.1-18)
- ... and independently with a development (`effects`) branch of the `glmmTMB` package (function call is identical)
- ... and independently with `nlme::lme`:

```
m3 <- nlme::lme(dep.var ~  ind.var * group.var,
            random=~1 | group, data=na.omit(d))
```

This suggests very strongly that your MacOS answer is correct.

I don't know why you're getting a different answer on Windows; the estimated standard errors can in principle be sensitive to numeric differences, but it's a little surprising for what seems to otherwise be a well-behaved model. My main advice for digging into this further would be to look farther upstream:

- are the fixed effects estimates the same (`fixef(.)`)? are the estimated standard errors of the coefficients (`sqrt(diag(vcov(.)))`)?
- are you **sure** that you are using the same data set, code, etc. on both platforms?

A couple of observations about your data:

- your response variable takes on the discrete values 1-7. Is this a Likert scale?  Depending on your approach and goals, a linear model might not be the most appropriate choice (it assumes that all neighbouring options are equidistant, e.g. the difference between responses '1' and '2' is the same as between '6' and '7'). One option would be to treat it as an ordinal response (see `ordinal::clmm` for mixed models with ordinal responses).
- your `group.var` is continuous. I was a little surprised - with that name, I was expecting it to be a categorical predictor (factor).
- since the predictors vary within groups you might want to consider a random-slopes model (e.g. `(ind.var*group.var|group)`; maybe overkill, but not ridiculous for a large data set)

Comment: Thank you very much.  I also asked my friends to run it on windows and they got the same results as I got on Mac.  It seems that the problem reproduces only on Windows that runs on Mac under Parallels software. I have compared all the outputs of lme4::lmer and nlme::lme, they all are identical, the source is `effects` package.

Comment: That's pretty strange, because the `effects` package doesn't really use very much from the model beyond the fixed-effect estimates and variance-covariance matrix. It would be worth letting the maintainers of `effects` know about this (`maintainer("effects")`), but given that it only reproduces under such specific/weird circumstances, it may be hard for them to diagnose & fix ...